# When an iphone Application install ,is there any package generated?

Tags: ios

I want to know that when i run iphone application in the simulator..that means it is installing,...so is there any package generated while installing,
I want to know the whole process behind installation of an iphone application.

Answer (score 0):

When running an iOS app from Xcode in the iOS Simulator, an app package is being created and placed here (for iOS 5.1 Simulator):

> ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/

The *.app* package is placed in a folder (whose name is a randomly generated identifier). You can right-click the *.app* package and choose "Show Package Contents" to view the bundled resources. The structure of the package is very similar to what is installed on a device, but the binary is compiled for i386 (instead of armvX), and there is no code signing in the Simulator.